# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 59)
```

Here is the script where such an error appears:

```
Line 59        if (obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url != undefined){
Line 60          array_Expanded_url.push([obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url]);
Line 61        } else {
Line 62         array_Expanded_url.push([""]); 
Line 63        }
```

The idea of `if` was exactly when the value was `undefined`, it would define in `else` the **empty value**, but this is not happening. Are there any errors in the script visibly that I can't see?

Comment: If would be easier to help you if you provided a [mcve] rather than a code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, I thought that in that situation, `urls` of `obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls` might not be included. So in order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
if (
  obj_data.data[int_i].entities.hasOwnProperty("urls") &&
  Array.isArray(obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls) &&
  obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url != undefined
) {
  array_Expanded_url.push([obj_data.data[int_i].entities.urls[0].expanded_url]);
} else {
  array_Expanded_url.push([""]); 
}
```

Comment: Perfectly solved the error, thank you very much!